# How to make a sidebar collapsed by default?

Tags: html, jquery, css, templates, bootstrap-4

I need to make a collapsed sidebar by default, it shows and hides with a button click, here is the template I am using :
[link to the template](https://demos.creative-tim.com/material-dashboard/examples/dashboard.html?_ga=2.186072105.1692131519.1600931588-1600928823.1600931588)

If you press Ctrl + Shift + i you will see the sidebar is minimized and a hamburger button is displayed to open the sidebar and hide it, how to make this by default on page load ?

Here is my code :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="fr">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Création de Production</title>
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="76x76" href="../assets/img/apple-icon.png">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="../assets/img/favicon.png">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1" />
    <meta content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0, shrink-to-fit=no' name='viewport' />
    <!--     Fonts and icons     -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../assets/css/css.css?family=Roboto:300,400,500,700|Roboto+Slab:400,700|Material+Icons" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../assets/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <!-- CSS Files -->
    <link href="../assets/css/material-dashboard.css?v=2.1.1" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>

<body>
    <div class="wrapper ">
        <div class="sidebar" data-color="purple" data-background-color="white" data-image="../assets/img/sidebar-1.jpg">
            <!--
          Tip 1: You can change the color of the sidebar using: data-color="purple | azure | green | orange | danger"

          Tip 2: you can also add an image using data-image tag
            -->
            <div class="logo" align="center">
                <img class="img-responsive center-blockmx-auto d-block" src={{ asset('/images/logo.svg') }} width="60%">
                <a href="#" class="simple-text logo-normal">
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="sidebar-wrapper">
                <ul class="nav">
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="./Admin">
                            <i class="material-icons">dashboard</i>
                            <p>Tableau de Bord</p>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="./Creation_produit">
                            <i class="material-icons">category</i>
                            <p>Création Produit</p>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item active">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="./Creation_production">
                            <i class="material-icons">timeline</i>
                            <p>Création Production</p>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="./Creation_poste">
                            <i class="material-icons">tablet_android</i>
                            <p>Création Poste</p>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="main-panel">
            <!-- Navbar -->

            <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-transparent navbar-absolute fixed-top ">
                <div class="container-fluid">
                    <div class="navbar-wrapper">
                        <ol class="breadcrumb">
                            <!--<li class="breadcrumb-item"><a href="#">Edition Rapports</a></li>-->
                            <li class="breadcrumb-item active" aria-current="page">Edition Rapports</li>
                        </ol>
                    </div>
                    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" aria-controls="navigation-index" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon icon-bar"></span>
                    </button>
                    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse justify-content-end">
                        <!--<form class="navbar-form">
                            <div class="input-group no-border">
                                <input type="text" value="" class="form-control" placeholder="Rechercher...">
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-white btn-round btn-just-icon">
                                <i class="material-icons">search</i>
                                <div class="ripple-container"></div>
                                </button>
                            </div>
                        </form>-->
                        <ul class="navbar-nav">
                            <li class="nav-item">
                                <a class="nav-link" href="#">
                                    <i class="material-icons">dashboard</i>
                                    <p class="d-lg-none d-md-block">
                                        Stats
                                    </p>
                                </a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                                <a class="nav-link" href="http://example.com" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                                    <i class="material-icons">notifications</i>
                                    <span class="notification">5</span>
                                    <p class="d-lg-none d-md-block">
                                        Some Actions
                                    </p>
                                </a>
                                <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
                                    <!--<a class="dropdown-item" href="#">1</a>
                                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">2</a>
                                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">3</a>
                                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another Notification</a>
                                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another One</a>-->
                                </div>
                            </li>
                            <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                                <a class="nav-link" href="#pablo" id="navbarDropdownProfile" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                                    <i class="material-icons">person</i>
                                    <p class="d-lg-none d-md-block">
                                        Compte
                                    </p>
                                </a>

                                <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownProfile">
                                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">
                                        <div class="alert alert-danger success-block">
                                            <strong>Bienvenue</strong>
                                        </div>
                                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Profile</a>
                                        <!--<a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Settings</a>-->
                                        <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="{{ url('/login/logout') }}">Déconnection</a>
                                </div>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>

            </nav>
            <!-- End Navbar -->
            <div class="content">
                <div class="container-fluid">
                    <div class="row">
               ...
```

Comment: It shows as collapsed when I load it

Comment: Maybe you are using a mobile device! in my pc it's not.

Comment: I loaded it on my PC and shrunk the window to get the hamburger menu to appear

Comment: That is what I meant, I need to make it display like this in a full size window

Comment: Hi there! We can surely help. Can you share some of your code to help you with a better and relatable answer :)

Comment: I just updated my poste